# Can't access a project running on a port on ubuntu server

Tags: angular, laravel, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, server

I created a project on localhost. Frontend is angular that runs on port 4200, backend is laravel that runs on port 8000. On my localhost. I run the backend using `php artisan serve` and it starts running on 8000, and for frontend i run `ng serve` and it serves the app on port 4200. Now I have deployed the app on EC2 instance with ubuntu 16.04. Installed LEMP stack on it. Cloned my project, Ran the commands to run frontend and backend apps. But when I enter the IP:port in the browser to access the app, it shows `This site can’t be reached 18.***.7.** refused to connect`. After running both commands the terminal shows that they are running.

I also used `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to see if the processes are running and it shows that both processes are running on 4200 and 8000 but still I can't access them.

[image]

See the screenshot. both ports are listening but I can't access them

EDIT: The security groups are as follows

All            | traffic All |   All    |   0.0.0.0/0

All traffic      All             All        ::/0

Custom TCP Rule  TCP             8000       0.0.0.0/0

Custom TCP Rule  TCP             8000       ::/0

SSH              TCP             22         0.0.0.0/0

NOTE: If I just enter the IP address of the server in browser, it shows me the nginx welcome page but IP:PORT gives this error

Comment: It looks like your service on port 8000 is bound to the `127.0.0.1` IP Address, this is also commonly known at `localhost` or `loopback`. As such, you will be able to access port 8000 locally from the server, but from no other devices on the network, even if the security groups are open.

Comment: Can you post your PHP config?

Comment: When nginx starts, it binds to some port and address on the local machine and waits for incoming requests.In your case it looks like it is bound to a specific ip of 127.0.0.1 and so it is inaccessible.Make the nginx server accessible on the 127.0.0.1 since it is back end and angular running on port 4200 accessible as *.  You can change the binding using ng server                                            
         authbind ng serve --port 80 --host   *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your localhost (127.0.0.1) is serving your application and specifically your 2 ports needed (8000 and 4200) as you can see in the image:
[image: Arrows showing where your ports are open]

The solution is serving your application on the IPv4/IPv6 interface rather than loopback/localhost so do not use Localhost:4200 in the webserver configuration; rather use 0.0.0.0:4200 (to listen on all interfaces) or [::]:80 so it can be accessed on port 80 (although it is depreciated because all hackers attack the standard http/https port which is port 80 first :D so stick with a custom/random port).
Refer to this link for more info on configuring the webserver: https://www.atlantic.net/hipaa-compliant-cloud-storage/how-to-install-lemp-stack-ubuntu-16-04/